# How to pass a single row of a 2D vector as a function argument

Tags: c++, 2d-vector

for each loop i'm trying to pass a single row of a vector v as a function argument but not able to do it correctly

```
    vector< vector<int> >v;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        vector<int>rows;
        for(int j=0;j<size;j++)
        {
            cin>>value;
            rows.push_back(value);
        }
        v.push_back(rows);
    }
    for(int i=n-2;i>=0;i--)
    {  
        int s=search(0,size-1,v[i],max);
    }
```

Comment: How is `v` defined?

Comment: @ Johnny Mopp for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            vector<int>rows;
            for(int j=0;j<size;j++)
            {
                cin>>value;
                rows.push_back(value);
            }
            v.push_back(rows);
        }

Comment: That's not a 2d vector. It should be `vector<vector<int>> rows;`

Comment: actually this is how i defined it


 vector< vector<int> >v;
     
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            vector<int>rows;
            for(int j=0;j<size;j++)
            {
                cin>>value;
                rows.push_back(value);
            }
            v.push_back(rows);
        }

Comment: Can you show us the parameters this `search()` function takes?

Comment: @ihavenoidea  int search(int beg,int end,vector<int>v,int element)

Comment: What exactly is the problem you're having? Are you having a compiler error? Please elaborate